# How to give color and style to one table in lyx

Tags: tables, color, lyx, backgrounds

I have been trying to do something like this in Lyx.

[image]

As you can see is a very simple style that I been trying to reproduce but without any success. I know there are to many questions related to this but I tried some of the answers but nothing seems to work. I also wanna know if there is a color package with a color like the one that I show in the image, I remembered reading something like this in another question that I can no find. I used the `xcolor` package but when I tried to generate the PDF, there was always an error except when I used the "basic" colors.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check `Help->Embedded Objects`, section 2.11.

Answer (score 3):

Start a table as usual in LyX using `Insert -> Table...` Load the `xcolor` package in the preamble with the `table` option:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

In the first cell of your table, select `Insert -> TeX Code` and write:

```
\rowcolor{blue!25}
```

For more information check `Help -> Embedded Objects`, section 2.11.

Comment: A possible addition: one can specify custom colors when using `xcolor`, for example `\definecolor{myowncolor}{rgb}{0.2, 0.4, 0.6}`. See section 2.5 of [the `xcolor` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you replay, now I wonder what about the line size/style, how can I put doble border instead of one single line or how can I increase the its size.

Comment: @user2343521, check the tool bar at the bottom when the cursor is inside the table. There are many options to activate/deactivate double borders, centering, etc.

Comment: @juliohm Gracias por tu respuesta. Of course that I have seen that tool bar, but I just see some options for general borders and the alignment of the text inside the cell, but nothing about the width of the border line. Until now the only thing that I have found about this is this command that allows to put double border line and not more  hline.

Comment: @user2343521, have you tried right-click `More... -> Settings...`?

Comment: Yes I have, but the options on the third label are never available,  besides there is nothing abouth the width of lineborder. I do not know if maybe this is because of the version of lyx

Comment: @user2343521, please check `Help -> Embedded Objects`, section 2.13.4 for line thickness. I recommend you to read in PDF (press Ctrl + R).

Comment: @juliohm Grande!!!, That is what I was lookinf for. Thanks a lot